# Junit Test case getting null point exception and cannot retrieve data from service layer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I am new to JUnit, I have written test cases for Service(Business layer) and Database layer(Hibernate Layer). When I was writing for backing bean, I am getting an error where I couldn't resolve. Have a look at the snippets attached and help me getting out of this frustration. I feel like I was not getting data from Service(Business) layer.But in my Bean I could print the list where as in for Junit test cases I am getting NULL.

method in **RepricingBeanTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={
"file:src/main/resources/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml",
    "file:src/main/resources/config/spring/beans/DataSourceTest.xml",
"file:src/main/resources/com/dynaprice/customer/spring/CustomerBean.xml"})
public class RepricingBeanTest {

RepricingBean beanrep = new RepricingBean();

@BeforeClass
public static void initialise() {

}
@Test
public void testGetRepricingRules() {
    int iSize = beanrep.getRepricingRules().size();
    assertNotNull(iSize);
}
```

method in **Repricingbean.java**

```
public List<Repricing> getRepricingRules(){
    return repricingBoimpl.getRepricingRules();
}
```

method in **RepricingBoimpl.java**

```
@Override
public List<Repricing> getRepricingRules() {
    return repricingDaoimpl.getRepricingRules();
}
```

method in **repricingDaoimpl.java**

```
public List<Repricing> getRepricingRules() {
        getHibernateTemplate().find("from Rule");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Repricing>repricingdata=getHibernateTemplate().find("from Repricing");
        System.out.println(repricingdata);
        return repricingdata;
    }
```

**Error I am getting**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dynaprice.RepricingBean.getRepricingRules(RepricingBean.java:364)
at com.dynaprice.beans.test.RepricingBeanTest.testGetRepricingRules(RepricingBeanTest.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RepricingBean beanrep = new RepricingBean();
```

You seem to be skipping Spring here completely, which means that...

```
return repricingBoimpl.getRepricingRules();
```

...might simply have no `repricingBoimpl` set (because Spring has no chance of interacting with this bean, so that instance isn't actually a spring managed bean, just some random object), which would explain the NPE. Try...

```
@Autowired
private RepricingBean beanrep;
```

...in your test class. If that doesn't work, post the part where the `RepricingBean` gets its `repricingBoimpl` set.

Comment: Error I am getting when I use @autowired                                                    No unique bean of type [com.dynaprice.RepricingBean] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [class com.dynaprice.RepricingBean]: expected at least 1 matching bean

Comment: I already posted all the layers how the flow will be from bean to database layer. I am getting it from services layer when I use sop statement, I can able to see the list in my console.

Comment: Then RepricingBean is not a Spring bean, which means, in your test you somehow have to get the repricingBoimpl and set it manually in your initialize() method. Since I do not know where your repricingBoimpl is normally coming from, it's hard to say where to get it from in your test.